# Comparing strings to user input with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that is kind of difficult to explain.

What I would like to do is look in a string of text, for example "hello". And each character in this string should be compared to user input, one by one.

If the text starts as full red, user presses "H" then the "h" letter of "hello" turns green, and the rest of the letters remain red.

How could I do this with javascript? Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Are you using a library such as jQuery or mooTools?

Comment: prefere not to include libraries, but if they provide a beautifully simple method I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var name = "Josh";

for( var i=0; i<name.length; i++ ){

  alert( name.charAt(i) );

}
```

Comment: how could I separate the fillStyle of the characters?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will need the `.charAt` method from `String.prototype`. Example:

```
var str       = "Hello world",
    userInput = "Helli world";

for(var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log( 'character at pos ', i, ' is: ', str.charAt( i ) === userInput.charAt( i ) );
}
```

Most browser also allow you to access characters using the bracket notation `str[i]` for instance.